# Generalized Quaternion Group

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

Let $w = e^{\Large\frac{i\pi}{n}} \in \mathbb{C}.$ Prove that the matrices $X=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    w & 0  \\
    0 & \overline{w}  \\
  \end{array}
\right)$ and $Y = \left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    0 & 1 \\
    -1 & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)$ generate a subgroup $Q_{2n}$ of order $4n$ in $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{C})$, with presentation $\langle x,y \mid x^n=y^2, x^{2n}=1, y^{-1}xy=x^{-1}\rangle.$

Comment: It is easy to prove that the matrices X and Y satisfy the conditions of the group with a given presentation, which will call $ G_{2n} $. Furthermore, we can use the Substitution Test for to ensure the existence of a surjective homomorphism between $ G_{2n} $ and $ Q_{2n} $. This proves that the order of $ G_{2n} $ is greater than or equal to $4n$. But I can not show that the order must be less than or equal to $4n$, which conclude the demonstration exercise.Any help please.Thanks.

Comment: Consider the exact sequence:$1\to \langle X\rangle \to G_{2n} \to \langle Y\rangle \to 1$. This sequence clearly splits, because $G$ is a semi-direct product of the two subgroups. Hence the order is as claimed. I am not sure if this is right, though.

Comment: @awllower there is no such exact sequence: $\langle X\rangle$ is a normal subgroup of order $2n$  while $\langle Y \rangle$ has order $4$, not $2$. The subgroups generated by $X$ and by $Y$ have a nontrivial intersection.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the group $G = \langle x,y \mid x^n=y^2, x^{2n}=1, y^{-1}xy=x^{-1}\rangle$. As noted by @AgenorAndrade, this group has order at least $4 n$, as it has your group as a homomorphic image.

To show that it as at most $4n$ elements, just note that every element of $G$ can be written as $x^{i} y^{j}$, for $0 \le i < 2n$, and $j \in \{0, 1\}$. In fact, in an arbitrary product of $x$ and $y$ and their inverses, the third relation
$$
y^{-1} x = x^{-1} y^{-1}, \quad\text{or}\quad y x = x^{-1} y 
$$
allows you to move all $y$ to the right, so you end up with
$$
x^i y^j,
$$
and then the second relation gives you $0 \le i < 2n$, and the first one tells you you just need to take $j \in \{0, 1\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider the group which is presented by $$G=\langle X,Y\mid X^n=Y^2,X^{2n}=1,Y^{-1}XY=X^{-1}\rangle$$ and then use the [von Dyck's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/vonDycksTheorem.html).

Comment: Babak (and another Theorem) to the rescue! + 1