# Representation of Generalised Quaternion Group over an extension of $\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

First of all really sorry for not a structured question.

I am reading some representations of Generalized Quaternion Group, specifically $Q_{16}$ whose order is $16$. I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305455/generalized-quaternion-group) question where $Q_{16}$ can be realised as matrices over $\mathbb C$. I am wondering if that can be done for integers or in some extension of integers. Specifically my question is

> Are there matrices in $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$ or $GL(n,\mathbb Z[\ast])$ for some integer $n$ and some root of unity $\ast$ such that the mtrices generate a group isomorphic to $Q_{16}$?

Sorry again if there is a mistake anywhere.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, this is true for all finite groups, by embedding first into $S_n$ and then using permutation matrices.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks.  So all I need to do is to get a permutation representation and then to matrix representation via permutation matrix. I get it.

Comment: But note that this might not be very efficient, since you might end up in $GL_{16}$ when smaller ones might have worked (I have no idea how small we can make do with here though).

Comment: Yes, that is a problem. matrix of dimension 16 will work. But indeed for my case a smaller one will be nice, but I am also unsure how to search for a smaller one.

Comment: Brauer proved that you can write any irreducible complex representation of a finite group $G$  over ${\mathbb Q}(\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is a primitive $|G|$-th root of unity. Perhaps you can write it over ${\mathbb Z}[   \lambda]$ but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G = \langle a,b \mid a^{2^n}=1,b^2=a^{2^{n-1}},b^{-1}ab=a^{-1} \rangle = Q_{2^{n+1}}$, and let $\omega$ be a primitive $2^n$th root of $1$.

Then $a \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{cc}\omega&0\\0&\omega^{-1}\end{array}\right)$,
$b \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\-1&0\end{array}\right)$, defines a faithful representation of $G$ over ${\mathbb{Z}}[\omega]$.

As has been pointed out in comments, by increasing $n$ you can get a representation over ${\mathbb Z}$.