# Commutative diagram of semidirect products

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, group-presentation, semidirect-product, group-extensions

My question is partly motivated by trying to solve [this one.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1936780/presentations-of-semidirect-product-of-groups) Let $E$ be the semidirect product of groups $G$ and $H$. Then, we have an exact sequence:

$$G \hookrightarrow^\iota G \rtimes_\phi H \twoheadrightarrow^\pi H$$

where $\phi\colon H \to \text{Aut}(G)$ is the action. I then formed the diagram:

$$\begin{array}{c}
F_G &\twoheadrightarrow& G \\
\downarrow_{\iota'} & & \downarrow_\iota\\ 
F_{G\rtimes H} & \twoheadrightarrow &G \rtimes H \\
\downarrow_{\pi'} & & \downarrow_\pi \\
F_H & \twoheadrightarrow & H
\end{array}$$

Each line is simply a group and the free group on it's generators. For instance, $F_G$ is the free group on the generators of $G$. The vertical short sequence on the right is given.

The left vertical sequence is constructed by the universal property of the free group. For instance, the map $\iota\colon G \to G\rtimes H$ defines a funtion from the basis of $F_G$ to $F_{G\rtimes H}$, and therefore the homomorphism $\iota'\colon F_G \to F_{G \rtimes H}$. Same thing for $\pi'$. It makes each square on the diagram to be commutative, and it also makes the left vertical sequence a short exact sequence.

But know, if I have a section $s\colon H \to G\rtimes H$, this would lift to a section $s'\colon F_H \to F_{G\rtimes H}$.

> This would mean that $F_{G \rtimes H}$ is isomorphic to $F_G
>  \rtimes F_H$, which seems very wrong, once free groups can't have
>   relations! I'm once again verifying all the steps, but I still
>   couldn't figure out where I got it wrong.

Comment: Why the downvote? What can I do to improve the question?

Comment: I don't think it's a bad question, and the downvote wasn't from me, but perhaps elaborate on the lemma(s?) that lead you to determine the isomorphism from the existence of sections?

Comment: @EthanMacBrugh Thanks, but unless it's necessary, I would prefer to not increase the already big size of the question. Here is a link to this construction: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339731/relation-between-semidirect-products-extensions-and-split-extensions

Comment: You refer a lot to the middle sequence and the left sequence, but there are horizontal and vertical sequences, so it is unclear what  you are referring to.

Comment: Why does your section on the right lift to a section on the middle? I'm not really sure what the point in introducing the left sequence is either. It seems like you're not using it anywhere.

Comment: @DerekHolt I've added explicit references to whether is the vertical or horizontal sequence. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @EthanMacBrugh the section $s$ defines a function from the basis of $F_H$ to elements of $F_{G \rtimes H}$. By the universal property, it lifts to a homomorphism $s'$. Know, the composition $\pi' \circ s'$ is the identity on all generators of $F_H$, by construction, and therefore it will be the identity for every element of $F_H$. The left vertical sequence really is pointless for this question (though I used it in my scribbles here). I'll remove it altogether.

Comment: The middle vertical sequence is not exact.

Comment: @DerekHolt it fails to be exact because $\ker(\pi') \neq \iota'(F_G)$, right? Of now, I'm struggling to show that equality and why $\pi'$ is surjective, and I think the latter is indeed true.