# Non-abelian group of order $p^3$ without semidirect products

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

I am trying to read a proof that there are at most two non-abelian groups of order $p^3$ if $p$ is an odd prime. The proof presents it as two cases: the first, where every non-identity element has order $p$, is fairly straight forward and results in the group generated by $a, b, c$, each of order $p$, with $ac=ca, bc=cb,$ and $aba^{-1}b^{-1} = c$.

The part that I am confused about is the second case, where there is an element of order $p^2$, called $a$. The author asserts that $G$ is then generated by $a$ and some $b$, where $b$ has order $p$. Why is this necessarily true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nonabelian group of order $p^3$ and semidirect products](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337771/nonabelian-group-of-order-p3-and-semidirect-products)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/337809/92067)  The initial problem allows use of semidirect product terminology, but the linked proof does not require it.

Answer (score 0):

Choose $b\notin <a>$. Can $ab \in <a>$?

Comment: But if $ab\not\in <a>$, why can't the order of $ab$ be different from $p^3$ ?

Comment: Did we not assume not abelian?

Comment: I see that $ab \not \in \langle a \rangle$, because then $a^{-1}ab = b \in \langle a \rangle$, but I don't see why I can conclude $|b| = p$. Why couldn't it be $p^2$?

Comment: @Luis No we didn't , did we ? and even if we assumed that the group is not abelian, I don't see why $ab$ must have an order of $p^3$ ?

Comment: Non-abelian is assumed. If it has order $p^3$, $G$ would be cyclic.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand you now. your hint was too short. Now why is it not possible that all elements of order $p$ are in $<a>$ ?

Comment: Dear Luis, I think there is something missing. Your argument as it stands now, does not seem to require anything about the oddness of $p$. However the result is false for the quaternions group

Comment: Yea I just realized that. I apologize.

Comment: How about we look at the cosets of $G/<a>$. This is a cyclic group of order $p$. This follows from the following Corollary in Dummit and Foot. If $G$ is a finite group of order $n$ and $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $G$, then any subgroup of index $p$ is normal.

Comment: @Luis $G/<a>$ may not be a group as $<a>$ need not be normal in $G$

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that. So there is some $b$ so $b\langle a \rangle$ has order $p$, but that just means $b^p \in \langle a \rangle$. I couldn't figure out why $b^p$ could not have order $p$ (and thus $b$ having order $p^2$)

Comment: @Amr Yes, it must be normal. That's the result he was stating: if a subgroup has index equal to the smallest prime dividing the order of a group then it is normal.  It's an extension of the much easier result that index 2 implies normal.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy agree. It must be normal, but then what ? Note that we need to use the oddness of $p$, because the desired result does not hold when $p=2$

Comment: What can you say if every element of $b<a>$ had order $p^2$?  The orders must be $1,p,p^2,p^3$.  By choice of $b$ we can rule out elements of order $1$; by non-abelian we can rule out orders of $p^3$.  So possible orders of elements of the coset are $p,p^2$.  If you can derive a contradiction to all of them having order $p^2$, then there you go. I don't know if this works (and in particular uses $p$ odd), but it's something to consider I think.