# Groups of order $p^3$, $p$ prime

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

I know that there are the abelian groups $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^3$, $\mathbb{Z}/p^2 \times \mathbb{Z}/p$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p^3$, and the non-abelian Heisenberg group of matrices $
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    1 & a & b \\
    0 & 1 & c \\
0 & 0 & 1
  \end{array} } \right]
$ where $a,b,c \in Z/p$.

I know that these are not all the groups in general because for $p=2$ we also have the quaternion group $H_8$ which is not in the list. Can we say anything more about the groups of order $p^3$ in general ?

Comment: For each $p$, there is a semidirect product corresponding to $\mathbb{Z} / \langle p \rangle$ acting on $\mathbb{Z} / \langle p^2 \rangle$ where the generator acts as multiplication by $1 + ap$ (where $a \in \mathbb{Z} / \langle p \rangle$ is a parameter).  I'm not sure which of these are isomorphic to each other, nor am I sure whether that might actually be isomorphic to the Heisenberg group when $a \ne 0$.  (For the case $a = 0$, it clearly just gives $\mathbb{Z}/\langle p^2\rangle \times \mathbb{Z}/\langle p\rangle$.)

Comment: Please ignore my "freshman level answer" in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/64406/11619). It is the other answers you want :-) Particularly Keith Conrad's and Arturo Magidin's.

Comment: There is a complete classification of all groups of order $p^3$, see [these notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf) by K. Conrad. See also other posts (there are many here), e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539723/an-easy-way-to-classify-groups-of-order-p3).